# Getting the max date from a list of date strings

Tags: date, python-3.6, datetime-format

I have a list of dates as strings:

```
dates = ['12/24/2017','7/7/2011','3/5/2016', '4/21/2018']
```

I want to get the most current date. However, I can't just use `max()` for this list.

```
max(dates)
>>> `7/7/2011'
```

Is there a simpler way (mod or library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max()` but you have to use the `key` param to convert the date string to true dates so they compare correctly, e.g.:

```
In []:
from datetime import datetime
max(dates, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y'))

Out[]:
'4/21/2018'
```

You could convert them all true dates and then just call `max()`:

```
In []:
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') for d in dates]
max(dates)

Out[]:
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 21, 0, 0)
```